# While running my next.js app that is using solidity smart contracts, I am getting "Cannot read properties of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, next.js, solidity, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

I was running my next.js app and trying to fetch user I am getting "cannot read properties of undefined" error

[image]

And **following error in the console**
[image]

Below is the code I was using

```js
import Ewitter from './Ewitter.json';
import ethers from 'ethers';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const ContractABI = Ewitter.abi;
const ContractAddress = '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3';
const Ethereum = typeof window !== 'undefined' && (window as any).ethereum;

const getEwitterContract = () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(Ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const EwitterContract = new ethers.Contract(
    ContractAddress,
    ContractABI,
    signer
  );

  return EwitterContract;
};

const useEwitter = () => {
  // const Ewitter = getEwitterContract();

  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState<string>('');
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<string>('');

  const connect = async () => {
    try {
      if (!Ethereum) {
        alert('Please install MetaMask');
        return;
      }
      const accounts = await Ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
      });
      if (accounts.length === 0) {
        alert('Please unlock MetaMask');
        return;
      }
      const account = accounts[0];
      console.log('connected to account: ', account);
        setCurrentAccount(account);
    } catch (errors) {
      console.log(errors);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!Ethereum){
        console.log("No ethereum wallet found, please install metamask")
        return ;
    }
    connect();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(currentAccount){
      getUser();
    }
  }, [currentAccount])

const getUser = async ()=>{
  const contract = getEwitterContract();
  const user = await contract.getUser(currentAccount);
  const {avatar, bio, name, username, wallet} = user;
  console.log(user);
  return user;
}

  return { connect, account: currentAccount };
};

export default useEwitter;
```

#**Update1**
I've changed `import ethers from 'ethers'`  to `import {ethers} from 'ethers'` and now I'm facing this error

[image]

If unable to understand properly or if you want to see the whole codebase then this is the **link to the github repo**

https://github.com/ChiragDogra/ewitter/blob/userIssue/dapp/hooks/useEwitter.ts

Answer (score 0):

believe or not I just had that issue.

the problem is how you are importing `ethers`. Should be

```
 import { ethers } from "ethers";
```

Comment: How to use useEffect bro can you please share the code

Comment: And I think the main problem was in in ethers, it was giving me undefined
Have a look at this
https://rollbar.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined/

Comment: **Problem 1** 
 In this line of code

```const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum as any);```

It is showing ```Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.```
Although I've checked for it, it is present in my window object.

**Problem 2**
In this line ``` setContract(EwitterContract)```
It is showing ```Argument of type 'Contract' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'.
  Type 'Contract' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.```

And it is complng with  `Call revert exception` err

Comment: @ChiragDogra I found the issue. `import { ethers } from "ethers";`